# Obtaining Large Signed Value in my QuickSort/InsertionSort Algorithm

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort

so my code is essentially working; however, I need clarification as to why when I implement insertion sort when I get to less than 20 elements in a subarray it adds a large signed value at the end when I print them out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int partitionMiddle (int arr[], int low, int high) {

    int pivot = arr[high];
    int i = (low - 1);

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }

    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}

void chooseMiddle....
void chooseMedian{code here...}

void insertionSort(int arr[], int low, int high){
    int j;
    for(int i = low+1; i <= high; i++){
        j = i;

        while(j>low && arr[j-1]> arr[j]){
            swap(arr[j], arr[j-1]);
            j= j-1;
        }
    }
}

void quickSortMiddle(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pi = partitionMiddle(arr, low, high);
    if (high-low > 20)
    {    
        quickSortMiddle(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSortMiddle(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
    else {
           insertionSort(arr, low, pi);
           insertionSort(arr, pi+1, high);   
   }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}


int main()
{
    clock_t x, k;
    x = clock();

    int arr[10000];
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for(int i =0; i<10000; i++) {
        arr[i] = (rand()%100)+1;
    }

    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    cout << "Original array: " ;
    printArray(arr, n);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "With Insertion Sort & Middle Element";

    chooseMiddle(arr, 0, n-1);
    quickSortMiddle(arr, 0, n-1);

    cout << endl;

    k = clock();

    // can comment this one vvvv or the previous one out to try them both
    cout << "With Insertion Sort & Median Element";

    chooseMedian(arr, 0, arr[((n-1)/2)], n-1);
    quickSortMiddle(arr, 0, n-1);

    cout << endl;

    k = clock();

    printf("Sorted array: ");
    printArray(arr, n);

    cout << endl;

    cout << "CPU Time : ";
    cout << k-x;

    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My expected results were to not just have -272632368 at the very end of my sorted array when I print it out. I think I went out of bounds in my insertion sort algorithm but I'm not sure as to where. Maybe someone with a better eye can catch it.

**** EDIT...So I went to debug the code on my own and it the number was appearing there somehow having to do with the n-1 parameter when I was calling the chooseMedian/chooseMiddle or quickSortMiddle functions. I changed it to simply being 'n'. I don't get why, but it's working now. If someone can explain why, that'd be helpful, but if not, that's okay too.

****EDIT2...So now that I have your attention, can you please explain to me why using pointers in the swap function is better than not? I found this example of a swap function online and don't know why they used pointers.

Comment: _when I get to less than 20 elements in a subarray it adds a large signed value at the end_ This sounds like an ["off-by-one-error"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Comment: I would take a closer look to the caller of the function which got the misteriously wrong value. (I would suspect the OB1 error there.) It's tedious but IMHO necessary to calculate in head (or on paper) the exact boundaries for the debug example and check/compare what the "life" values of variables show.

Comment: Yes, going through it like that is tedious...however but necessary. I will look into doing that next time. Thank you.

Comment: If they/you didn't use pointers the `swap()` would swap its local parameters but not the values in original storages of arrays. Pointers are in C++ the 2nd best option. Usually, `std::swap` uses references: `swap(int &a, int &b) { int t = a; a = b; b = t; }` is IMHO nicer. Changing the `swap`, you have to remove the `&` from the call arguments, of course.

Comment: The large signed value is probably the result of doing a debug build where what would normally be uninitialized memory is filled with a pattern like 0xccccccc or 0xcdcdcdcd, ... .

Comment: @rcgldr _Changing the swap, you have to remove the `&` from the call arguments, of course._ was meant as: With `void swap(int &a, int &b) { int t = a; a = b; b = t; }` instead of `void swap(int *a, int *b) { int t = *a; *a = *b; *b = t; }`, the call `swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);` had to be changed to `swap(arr[i], arr[j]);` i.e. drop the `&` (address operators) in arguments. Sorry, if I produced confusion...

Comment: @Scheff - "misunderstand each other" - yes, my fault. I thought you were commenting on the caller, not the callee, when you mentioned the parameters for std::swap. This does point out one of the issues I have with the way C++ implemented callee declared references without having it clear in the caller code if it's pass by value or pass by reference (can the variables be changed by the callee?) I deleted my prior comments, I'll delete this one later.